# asterisk is not displayed correctly next to input on click event

Tags: jquery

can someone please tell me why when I click Edit in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gGzr9/6/), asterisk is not lined up with input field but is shown on the bottom.
CSS

```
.required-field::after {
    display: none;
    content: "*";
    color: red;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

JS

```
 $("p").on('click', function(){     
              var $style = $('<style>');
                $style.appendTo('head');
                var base = ".required-field::after{display:block;}";
                $style.html(base);
                });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `display:inline` instead of block

```js
 $("p").on('click', function(){     
              var $style = $('<style>');
                $style.appendTo('head');
                var base = ".required-field::after{display:inline;}";
                $style.html(base);
                });
```

```css
.required-field::after {
    display: none;
    content: "*";
    color: red;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mvnDefinitionInput required-field'>
<input type='text' class='mvnDefinitionFieldExtraInput'/>
</div>
<p class='editDefMVN"'><span>Edit</span></p>
```

Comment: No problem =) .Can u check this answer as accepted pleased?